# get openshift public key

Tags: mongodb, openshift, public-key, replicaset

I am currently trying to set up mongodb replica set using two digital ocean droplets and one openshift gear. When I try to obtain the openshift gear public key under .ssh directory I got "permission denied". Does any of you guys know if it is possible to get the public key from an openshift gear? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create your own public/private key pair and use them.  I suggest storing them in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.  You (as a user) do not have access to the ~/.ssh directory on your gear.  You can use the ssh-keygen command to create a new keypair.

Comment: Thank you! Would ssh pick it up? Say that I wish to open a local port forwarding from openshift to another server that's running sshd service, would it work if I generate a public/private key pair and upload the public key to the other server's authorized_keys?

Comment: You would need to use the -i option to specify the key that you want to use.